# Error when trying to run a database synchronisation

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-2008, synchronization, microsoft-sync-framework

I am trying to synchronise 3 SQL Server 2008 tables to a SQL Server CE 3.5 database. The following code produces the error at the bottom. Any ideas whats going on? The tracking tables exist as well as the stored procedures.

Thanks

Code:

```
SyncLibrary.DatabaseSyncInfo inf = new SyncLibrary.DatabaseSyncInfo();
SynchronizationHelper hel = new SynchronizationHelper(inf);

inf.LocalConnectionString = @"Data Source=admin.domain.com,1435;Initial Catalog=ProjectAdmin;User ID=sa;Password=password";
inf.LocalDriverType = SyncLibrary.eSyncDriverType.SQLServer;

inf.RemoteConnectionString = @"Data Source=C:\Projects\Admin\TCPClient\ProjectAdmin.sdf";
inf.RemoteDriverType = SyncLibrary.eSyncDriverType.SQLCompact;
inf.ScopeName = "ProjectSCOPE";

System.Collections.Generic.List<string> tables = new System.Collections.Generic.List<string>();
tables.Add("Users");
tables.Add("SB_Questions");
tables.Add("Kiosks");

inf.SyncTables = tables;

SyncOperationStatistics ss = hel.DoSync();

Console.WriteLine("Start time: " + ss.SyncStartTime);
Console.WriteLine("Total changes uploaded: " + ss.UploadChangesTotal);
Console.WriteLine("Total changes downloaded: " + ss.DownloadChangesTotal);
Console.WriteLine("Complete time: " + ss.SyncEndTime);

public SyncOperationStatistics DoSync()
{
        SqlSyncProvider localProvider = ConfigureSqlServerSyncProvider(new SqlConnection(this.dbInfo.LocalConnectionString));

        RelationalSyncProvider remoteProvider = null;
        if (dbInfo.RemoteDriverType == eSyncDriverType.SQLServer)
        {
            remoteProvider = ConfigureSqlServerSyncProvider(new SqlConnection(this.dbInfo.RemoteConnectionString));
        }
        else if (dbInfo.RemoteDriverType == eSyncDriverType.SQLCompact)
        {
            remoteProvider = ConfigureSqlServerCeSyncProvider(new SqlCeConnection(this.dbInfo.RemoteConnectionString));
        }

        //Set memory data cache size property. 0 represents non batched mode
        localProvider.MemoryDataCacheSize = dbInfo.LocalBatchSize;
        remoteProvider.MemoryDataCacheSize = dbInfo.RemoteBatchSize;

        //Set batch spool location. Default value if not set is %Temp% directory.
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(dbInfo.LocalBatchSpoolFolder) == false)
        {
            localProvider.BatchingDirectory = dbInfo.LocalBatchSpoolFolder;
        }

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(dbInfo.RemoteBatchSpoolFolder) == false)
        {
            remoteProvider.BatchingDirectory = dbInfo.RemoteBatchSpoolFolder;
        }

        SyncOperationStatistics stats = this.SynchronizeProviders(localProvider, remoteProvider);

        //TimeSpan diff = stats.SyncEndTime.Subtract(stats.SyncStartTime);
        //Print Sync stats object
        //this.syncStats.Text = string.Format("Batching: {4} - Total Time To Synchronize = {0}:{1}:{2}:{3}",
        //    diff.Hours, diff.Minutes, diff.Seconds, diff.Milliseconds, (this._batchSize > 0) ? "Enabled" : "Disabled");
        //this.ReadTableValuesForSelectedTab();
        return stats;
    }
```

Error:

> Cannot apply changes because the local provider does not have adapters configured for the following tables that were received from the remote provider: Kiosks. Ensure that the correct adapters have been added to both providers for Scope 'ProjectSCOPE', and that any table mapping has been correctly configured.

Comment: can you check inside the scope_info table if the xml of the scope config actually contains the table?

Answer (score 1):

In my case client provisioning was different from Server provisioning. I have de-provision database and applied provisioning. After that this error is removed.

```
        try
        {
            SqlSyncScopeDeprovisioning obj1 = new SqlSyncScopeDeprovisioning(clientConn) { CommandTimeout = 60 * 30 };
            obj1.DeprovisionScope(scopeName);
        }
        catch { }

        // get the description of ProductsScope from the SyncDB server database
        DbSyncScopeDescription scopeDesc = SqlSyncDescriptionBuilder.GetDescriptionForScope(scopeName, serverConnection);

        SqlSyncScopeProvisioning clientProvision = new SqlSyncScopeProvisioning(clientConn, scopeDesc);

        if (!clientProvision.ScopeExists(scopeName))
        {
            //apply the scope definition
            clientProvision.Apply();
        }
```

Comment: In my case, I found out that de-provisioning only the local database was not enough to fix the error and so I had to de-provision the remote SQL sync scope as well.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there is a mismatch in table name on your remote database and local database.

Try using GlobalName property on TableDescription. For example if there is two tables with name Countries_Version and Countries but they do exposes same data and the only difference is name you can do something like below to get is mapped via GlobalName property.

```
        DbSyncTableDescription CountriesTableDescription;
        if (provider.Connection.Database.ToLower() == "peer1")
            CountriesTableDescription = SqlSyncDescriptionBuilder.GetDescriptionForTable( "Countries_Version", (System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection)provider.Connection );
        else
            CountriesTableDescription = SqlSyncDescriptionBuilder.GetDescriptionForTable( "Countries", (System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection)provider.Connection );

        // map to the Countries_Version table on peer2
        CountriesTableDescription.GlobalName = "Countries";
```

Comment: Also verify the config_data XML from the scope_config table for the table which is causing an error. In my case the issue was only that on server config it has not mentioned the schema and on local it had the schema name prefixed. I manually updated the config xml on server and it did the job.